# Can a write scheduler be optimized using pending writes, total writes, and total bytes written?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, io

I'd like to confirm that this interview question is essentially impossible:

> The goal of this project is to create an implementation of a device
>   that can write files to a directory and then to design a write
>   scheduling system for a set of devices. The write scheduler system
>   should consist of an interface named WriteScheduler and at least two
>   concrete implementations of it. The first should be a fair round robin
>   scheduler and the second should be a write scheduler that uses some
>   combination of pending writes, total writes, and total bytes written
>   to optimize the writes in some way. All code for this project should
>   be thread-safe.

Given an unspecified interface, how could a scheduler be optimized with just that data?

Answer (score 1):

It says "...to optimize the writes **in some way**".

So exactly what you attempt to optimize *for* is apparently pretty much up to you. For that matter, it may not even be particularly important that your attempted optimization be highly (or at all) successful.

If I had to guess, I'd say they're probably mostly interesting in the basic idea that you can define an abstract interface, then write a couple of implementations of that interface that differ in at least some semi-meaningful way (but still meet the interface's specification).

Comment: Sounds like they were looking for you to describe something using a Strategy pattern:

http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern

Answer (score 1):

I presume, that the tag c++ was a mistake?

Ok, to the subject:

**I can imagine an interface from what you provide us as this...**

IDevice: this interface can be even empty interface

Device:

- must implement IDevice interface,
- constructor consumes IWriteScheduler instannce,
- must be thread safe for next ops,
- method open(string path),
- method create(string path),
- method read(out byte[] buffer, int attempt_read_n),
- method write(in byte[] buffer),
- method close(),
- device will place lock around all public methods,
- all methods will be potentially blocking,

Now IWriteScheduler:

- Task WriteAsync(IDevice device, int size, Action writing_task)

Device behaviour:

- Device in write operation is going to create an action with operation
  to write data into a file,
- calling an instance of IWriteScheduler:
  IWriteScheduler.WriteAsync(this, 41561, action) and then waiting on it,
- OR the Device can return the Task back to caller of Write operation,
  to let it decide if waiting is appropriate,
- that is all,

WriteScheduler:

- will implement IWriteScheduler,
- has to have a lock on WriteAsync operation,
- private class DevicesData
  {IDevice, total_bytes, pending_writes, total_writes, Task last_task }
  initial last_task has to be task_completed, could be created under 
  older .net versions,
- has to implement dictionary,
- **virtual WriteAsync method**, the default implementation would be
  round robin, 
  what means that in BlockingWrite method, the scheduler would update the
  correct DeviceData based on dictionary key IDevice and used last_task
  of the DeviceData to start next one by chaining based on ContinueWith,
- simple chaining of tasks is going to ensure round robin scheduling,

Other scheduling methods simply by inheriting from WriteScheduler, overriding the:

virtual Task WriteAsync(IDevice device, int size, Action writing_task);

Task chaining allows to put even delays on write operations and many more tricks.

For scheduiling based on on the pending_writes, total_writes and total_bytes, well there is many ways to schedule and build specific rules that such data structure could handle:

- there could be writes per second,
- there could be bytes per second,
- these could help to keep hard drives from burning out :),
- both could be handled with data structure by inserting tasks with
  thread.sleep what would work, but would be awful :),
- a better solution for delays would be Thread.Timer inside DeviceData
  and an queue of writing tasks.

**I hope it was helpful, I provided analysis on implementation of the interface and some ideas for scheduling scenarios...**

**/IP/**